# Regex to match only strings containing alphabets

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have a list of strings:

```
Mr 1
Mr 1-ta
Mr Charles Darwin
Mr John Smith
Mr 100
```

and I want to write a regex where it only matches the string with no numeric elements in it, in this case, the **following strings should not be matched**

```
Mr 1
Mr 1-ta
Mr 100
```

and the strings that **will be matched** is:

```
Mr Charles Darwin
Mr John Smith
```

The regex I currently have is:

```
^(Mr\s)(.*)$
```

How do i modify it in such a way where it would only consider alphabetical elements after the **Mr** ? There is a notation [a-zA-Z], but how do I combine it with the (.*) notation?

Comment: Something like `^Mr(?:\s[A-Z][a-z]+)+$` would match what you are after.

Comment: @JvdV *Đuro Šimac*  is not a Mr.?

Comment: @JvdV, the brackets between `Z][a` are unnecessary ;)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, I guess I went with the examples given by OP, your comment is valid if these type of names could occur in his dataset. Also, `[A-Z][a-z]+` would ensure each part of the true names starts with a single capital followed by 1+ lowercase alpha-chars. To Match your example, maybe `^Mr(?: \p{Lu}\p{Ll}+)+$` is better.

Answer (score 2):

The comment-answer by @JvdV is fine, but you could also do this simply using a negative lookahead:

```regex
^(?!.*\d)Mr(?: \w+)+$
```

### Demo

Explanation of regex:

```regex
^          from the start of the string
(?!.*\d)   assert that no digits are present
Mr         then match "Mr"
(?: \w+)+  followed by one or more name terms (a name being \w+)
$          end of the string
```

Comment: [Fran Galović](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran_Galovi%C4%87) is not a *Mr.*?

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `\D` to allow it match any non-digit after matching `Mr` and following space:

```
^Mr\s\D+$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yPZPIS/1)

**Explanations:**

- `^`: Start
- `Mr\s`: Match `Mr` followed by a whitespace
- `\D+`: Match 1+ non-digit characters
- `$`: End

Comment: :D was it on purpose, right? https://regex101.com/r/rB2Ukk/1

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: Online demo sometimes can play tricks when match goes beyond a line break and here `\D` matches a line break also. For your demo you can use: `^Mr\s[^\d\n]+$`

Comment: OK, but in that case why you use the `$` after doing `\D+` (in your suggested `^Mr\s\D+$`)?

Comment: `$` is required here only for online demo to stop match at line break since `\D` also matches a line break, otherwise inside code if OP is not matching multiple strings per line then `$` can be skipped. btw `^Mr\s[^\d\n]+` won't require a `$`

Comment: Exactly that. Thank you for explaining (BTW I was about to answer the exact same - the reason for being so nitpicky ;))

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, don't forget that the title also explicitly states to find strings that only contain alpha-chars. `\D` would allow for so much more. Just a heads-up =)

Comment: @JvdV I understand your concerns. And there are so many symbols for names we cannot even imagine.  I would be quite happy with \D honestly. Actually I'm not even happy with \D but it's quite good. We should ask E. Musk's son what he thinks about it.

Comment: Catching names through regex is notoriously difficult =) @RokoC.Buljan